# print out the pattern in an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list which contains 3 machines in python which is `ARRAY_MACHINE= ['machine1', 'machine2', 'machine3']`

And, I want to write a script that can access 2 or 3 items at a same time in that list (depend on the array). If the `ARRAY_MACHINE` has 3 items like above, it will print out

```
The machines are machine1, machine2, machine3
```

If the `ARRAY_MACHINE` has 2 items, it will print out.

```
The machines are machine1, machine2
```

How can I do that? So far, I used `while loop` to do that, and it can only loop through each item in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join`:

Python 3:

```
>>> ARRAY_MACHINE= ['machine1', 'machine2', 'machine3']
>>> print('The machines are {}'.format(', '.join(ARRAY_MACHINE)))
The machines are machine1, machine2, machine3

>>> ARRAY_MACHINE= ['machine1', 'machine2']
>>> print('The machines are {}'.format(', '.join(ARRAY_MACHINE)))
The machines are machine1, machine2
```

Python 2:

```
>>> ARRAY_MACHINE= ['machine1', 'machine2', 'machine3']
>>> print 'The machines are {}'.format(', '.join(ARRAY_MACHINE))
The machines are machine1, machine2, machine3

>>> ARRAY_MACHINE= ['machine1', 'machine2']
>>> print 'The machines are {}'.format(', '.join(ARRAY_MACHINE))
The machines are machine1, machine2
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. That's print statement suppose to be a command on Linux. And, I was struggle a lot using bash script to do it (since, they are terrible in loop). Thank you a lot :)

Comment: @Alexander If you are using `python2`, `print` is a statement..in `python3` (As i have used) its a function..

Comment: I will replace that print statement by a command in Linux. And, I will check the version if Python in my company later

Answer (score 2):

`print "The machines are" , ', '.join(ARRAY_MACHINE)`

This will do the job nicely.

Join function will join the elements of an array with the delimiter specified.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import sys
ARRAY_MACHINE= ['machine1', 'machine2', 'machine3']

for i, data in enumerate(ARRAY_MACHINE):
    if(i == 0 ):
        sys.stdout.write ("The machines are ")
    sys.stdout.write (data+" ")
```